# Visual C++ Redistributable installation failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-c++-runtime

I want to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable on my pc working on Windows 7 64-bit.

But every time I do it gives an error as follows:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Did you look in the log file? Do you have SP1 installed? https://superuser.com/questions/979546/vc-redist-x86-exe-setup-failed-0x80240017-unspecified-error  This may also be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1092280/0x80240017-error-while-installing-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable

Comment: No, SP1 is not installed. Is there any other way i can run unity without having this distribution?

Comment: @SaranshKhurana post the log. It's impossible to guess by the error number. It could easily be a bad download. Where did you download that file from?

Comment: I have downloaded it from official microsoft site. Let me edit log in question description

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That error is `WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE` which means that redist is not for that Windows installation or there is something else superseding it. Knowing now that the OP does not have SP! that's why it isn't installing.

Comment: The system requirements for Unity are SP1+. https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements

Comment: Come to think of it, Windows 7 RTM is no longer supported, period. It went out of support in 2013. Unity maintainers are well within their rights to require a *supported* environment. [Windows 7 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) reaches the end of extended support in 2020

Comment: So i have to change my pc i guess ;--;